# Upload compressed data to Google BigQuery using API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, logstash

For the past couple of days i've been working to improve the logstash google_bigquery connector.
Currently i was able to add features such as error handling (bad lines), better connection management and couple of other stuff.

the last but most important feature that i'm been working on is uploading compressed data to BigQuery and well the documentation of the API is horrible.

for now i'm able to uploading CSV files directly to BQ using the Jobs.insert method
and i've noted that its clearly written that data can be uploaded compressed.

the only question left is there a way i can do so without using Google Cloud Storage, as the compressed option is there to reduce the network bandwidth and its cost, and adding another route (that cost money) such as GCS is pointless

the error code i'm getting is:

> BQ: job failed, please enable debug and check full response (probably
>   the issue is an incompatible schema). NOT deleting local file.
>   {:job_id=>"job_OvWTWOXGv9yGnLKfrTfGfukLytM",
>   :filename=>"/Users/dave.e/Logstash/tmp/bq-logstash_daves-mpb.local_2014-08-26.part000.log.gz",
>   :job_status=>{"state"=>"DONE",
>   "errorResult"=>{"reason"=>"internalError", "location"=>"File: 0",
>   "message"=>"Unexpected. Please try again."},
>   "errors"=>[{"reason"=>"internalError", "location"=>"File: 0",
>   "message"=>"Unexpected. Please try again."}]}, :level=>:error}

I'll cut to the main case with the code and be grateful for your help

```
  # Uploads a local file to the configured bucket.
  def upload_object(filename)
    @logger.debug("entering upload_object")
    begin
      @logger.debug("1")
      require 'json'
      @logger.debug("2")
      table_id = @table_prefix + "_" + get_date_pattern(filename)
      @logger.debug("3")
      # BQ does not accept anything other than alphanumeric and _
      # Ref: https://developers.google.com/bigquery/browser-tool-quickstart?hl=en
      table_id = table_id.gsub(':','_').gsub('-', '_')
      @logger.debug("table bane has been modified")

      @logger.debug("BQ: upload object.",
                    :filename => filename,
                    :table_id => table_id)
      media = Google::APIClient::UploadIO.new(filename, "application/octet-stream")
      body = {
        "configuration" => {
          "load" => {
            "sourceFormat" => "NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON",
            "schema" => @json_schema,
            "destinationTable"  =>  {
              "projectId" => @project_id,
              "datasetId" => @dataset,
              "tableId" => table_id
            },
            'createDisposition' => 'CREATE_IF_NEEDED',
            'writeDisposition' => 'WRITE_APPEND',
            'maxBadRecords' => 99
          }
        }
      }

      @logger.debug("Execution details: ",
                   :body_object => body,
                   :parameters => {
                     'uploadType' => 'multipart',
                     'projectId' => @project_id
                   },
                  :media => media)

      datasetId = @project_id+":"+@dataset

      verify_dataset = @client.execute(:api_method => @bq.datasets.get,
                                       :parameters => {
                                         'projectId' => @project_id,
                                         'datasetId' => datasetId })

      status = JSON.parse(verify_dataset.response.body)["id"]
      if status != dataset
         @logger.info("BQ: dataset doesnt exist, creating it instead")
         create_dataset = @client.execute(:api_method => @bq.datasets.insert,
                                          :parameters => { 'projectId' => @project_id },
                                          :body_object => { 'id' => datasetId })
         sleep 10
      end

      insert_result = @client.execute(:api_method => @bq.jobs.insert,
                                      :body_object => body,
                                      :parameters => {
                                        'uploadType' => 'multipart',
                                        'projectId' => @project_id
                                      },
                                      :media => media)

      job_id = JSON.parse(insert_result.response.body)["jobReference"]["jobId"]
      @logger.debug("BQ: multipart insert",
                    :job_id => job_id)
      return job_id
    rescue => e
      @logger.error("BQ: failed to upload file", :exception => e)
      # TODO(rdc): limit retries?
      sleep 1
      if File.exist?(filename)
        retry
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: I've never used BigQuery from ruby, but I do recommend using resumable upload instead of multipart (yes, this is supported in bigquery,  I think a lot of docs may not mention it). More info here: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/ruby/guide/media_upload.

Comment: I'm investigating the error ... according to our logs the input file was only 9107 bytes. Is correct, or is part of the file missing?

Comment: i think its correct
i'm trying to debug it will small packages of data, as i dont want to try it out at first with 100G files

Comment: and thanks for the resumable part advise, acctually i was aware of that.
i didn't think of using it but maybe i should implement it for cases of files larger than X

Answer (score 1):

The error on our side was that the file did not appear to be a valid gzip file, and the gzip library was unable to open it.

This could be a problem with how the file was generated or with how it was uploaded. If you still have access to the file, can you verify that you're able to unzip it?

Comment: Hi finally after a long weekend i came to the point that i can verify that the data is compressed and can be uncompressed as well.

and yet from time to time i'm getting the same kind of error or a message of hitting my dailyQuota, which is really odd as i'm testing it with a new table (avoiding the 1000 loads per day limitation) and i'm 8K loads behind the project limitation loads quota 

if you'd like we can communicate by mail and once we figure it out we can publish the results here so people know whats where and how